# XAF Devexpress add button to the grouped row in web ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xaf

I have been going crazy with this issue it seems like its impossible to be achieved within XAF/XPO ! *(I posted this question to devexpress support also but maybe some of you may have encountered this problem sometime)*

I have a **business object which I have grouped by an attribute**.

Now I want to add a **BUTTON WHICH WILL BE INLINE WITH THIS ROW**, in other words I should not add a button for each row of the grid, but only for rows that can be expanded (that are grouped).

I have seen a tons of other threads, but they either address a WinForms application or they refer to ASPxGridView control .

All I want is to create some controller which inherits from the view and make the proper modification, saying that, I do not want to create some new templates, or to have to modify HTML.

Please, any kind of help would be immensely helpful.

Thank you !!

[SCREENSHOT HERE button to be placed where blue arrows indicate; NOT where the 'X' button is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSkPT.png)

Comment: If you know the solution for WinForms or ASP.NET Grid control, you can use it in an XAF application, too. This article describes how to [Access Grid Control Properties](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113165/Getting-Started/Comprehensive-Tutorial/Extend-Functionality/Access-Grid-Control-Properties).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for commenting ! All solutions on WinForms, point out the fact that there must be a data source from where to fetch data (in my case I use XAF therefore the ASP.NET Controls are created on the fly and no data source is specified)

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1671/how-to-use-custom-aspxgridview-template-in-a-web-xaf-application    It says : **_You can achieve the same result in XAF. The difference is that you will need to create controls dynamically_**